# Are amazon workspaces connected to the same network?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, amazon-workspaces

Any one knows if two stations created with the same amazon aws workspaces account share the same network ? Are they linked in any way ? Should I use vpn on each one if I want that they stay independent ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have created a workspace in the same AWS VPC, they will be deployed in the same virtual network.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/workspaces/latest/adminguide/amazon-workspaces-vpc.html

If you require that they are to be running on completely segregated networks, creating multiple VPCs would be your best option. Though with the security groups, you should be able to not allow the 2 workspaces to communicate with each other by ensuring that the inbound rules don't allow any connections to said workspace.